# Android - Cursor not finding Column

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the results from a Cursor and put them in into an Object that I created.  In Eclipse, it appears the cursor is returning a single row (which is what I want) but when I try to access it, I get an error.  Here's the code to fetch a single row:

```
public Object fetchIssue(long IssueNumber, int type){

    //Get query cursor.
    Cursor cursor = mDB.query(true, ISSUES_TABLE, ISSUES_COLUMN_ARRAY, COL_ISSUE_ID + "=" + IssueNumber, null, null, null, null, null);

    int iCount = cursor.getCount();

    if(cursor == null)
        return null;

    Object objOut = null;

    if(type == QUERY_TYPE_STRING_ARRAY){
        //Create Array to hold Issue Information.
        String[] IssueInfo = new String[3];
        IssueInfo[0] = String.valueOf(IssueNumber);
        IssueInfo[1] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DATE_RECEIVED));
        IssueInfo[2] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_SUMMARY));
        IssueInfo[3] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_STATUS));
        IssueInfo[4] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_SUB_STATUS));
        IssueInfo[5] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION));
        objOut = IssueInfo;
    }
    else{
        //Create IssueInfo object.
        IssueInfo IssueInfo = new IssueInfo(
                    IssueNumber, "12/12/2000",
                    //cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DATE_RECEIVED)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_SUMMARY)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_STATUS)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_SUB_STATUS)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION)));
        objOut = IssueInfo;
    }

    //Close cursor.
    cursor.close();

    //Return IssueInfo.
    return objOut;
}
```

iCount returns 1 and if I put the cursor variable in the "variables" window, I can see all the columns:
[image: Cursor variable]

and at the top of the class, the table column variables are set to the same name:

```
public static final String ISSUES_TABLE = "Issues";
public static final String COL_ISSUE_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_DATE_RECEIVED = "DateReceived";
public static final String COL_ISSUE_STATUS = "IssueStatus";
public static final String COL_ISSUE_SUB_STATUS = "IssueSubStatus";
public static final String COL_ISSUE_SUMMARY = "IssueSummary";
public static final String COL_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION = "IssueDescription";

private static final String[] ISSUES_COLUMN_ARRAY = new String[]{
    COL_ISSUE_ID, COL_DATE_RECEIVED, COL_ISSUE_SUMMARY, 
    COL_ISSUE_STATUS, COL_ISSUE_SUB_STATUS, COL_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION};
```

The error is occuring on this line:

```
//Create IssueInfo object.
        IssueInfo IssueInfo = new IssueInfo(
                    IssueNumber, "12/12/2000",
                    //cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DATE_RECEIVED)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_SUMMARY)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_STATUS)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_SUB_STATUS)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION)));
```

or any of those lines (as you can see, I commented out the Date Received and put a normal string value in there, which it takes).

Here's the error:

```
03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.adacel.dashboard.DBAdapter.fetchIssue(DBAdapter.java:215)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.adacel.dashboard.IssueInfoCreator.fetchIssue(IssueInfoCreator.java:42)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.adacel.dashboard.ViewIssue.LoadIssueDetails(ViewIssue.java:73)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.adacel.dashboard.ViewIssue.access$0(ViewIssue.java:70)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.adacel.dashboard.ViewIssue$GetIssueDetailsTask.doInBackground(ViewIssue.java:96)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.adacel.dashboard.ViewIssue$GetIssueDetailsTask.doInBackground(ViewIssue.java:1)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    03-13 09:06:42.370: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     ... 4 more
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I normally do a cursor.moveToFirst() before trying to access column data, perhaps try this?  Make sure it returns bool true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always move the Cursor to an element, after you query it:

```
if(cursor == null)
    return null;
if(!cursor.moveToFirst()) //this will move the cursor to the first element
    return null;
```

if you expect multiple rows a better way to do it is:

```
if(cursor != null) {
   cursor.move(-1);
   while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: That works!  Thanks a bunch....been looking this over thinking it had to be something simple.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

you will have to move to first index of the cursor first:

```
 cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

try modify the size of IssueInfo:

```
String[] IssueInfo = new String[3];
```

to

```
String[] IssueInfo = new String[6];
```

And change the name of the object IssueInfo to other like issue_info

Comment: well the error is coming from the ELSE part of the statement, not the first part where the String array is used.  I don't think that will effect anything.

Comment: ok, i don't read this. But the error was in cursor.moveToFirst() (as they have answered)