# Cannot get email from ContactsContract

Tags: java, android, uri, contactscontract

No matter what I try, it does not work. 
I've tried googling and using many examples posted here before, I still keep getting indexOutOfBoundsException.

Here is my code snippet.

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();



                String[] mProjection =
                        {

                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA

                        };



                Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData,mProjection, null, null, null);

                myEmail = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(mProjection[2]));

                Log.d("EMAIL RESULT", myEmail);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question: [Android - Cursor not finding Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684602/android-cursor-not-finding-column)

Your code seems to be lacking this:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me:

```
    Cursor c;

    String[] projection = new String[]
            { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email._ID,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS
            };

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            this,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    c = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    getEmails(c);
```

and your getEmails method:

```
 private void getEmails(Cursor c) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String contactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email._ID));
                String contactDisplayName =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
                String contactEmail =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));


            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```